# Spring изменение логирования из logback на log4j2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, логирование, log4j2, logback

Как изменить логер в спринге с logback на log4j2?

В режиме дебага спринг выводит инфу в консоль. Этим занимается либа logback.

Log4J2 конфигурация:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error" monitorInterval = "30">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [thread-id %T] %l - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="/log.log" filePattern="/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.spring.*" level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы заменить библиотеку логирования в Spring Boot, нужно исключить из зависимостей `spring-boot-starter-logging` и добавить `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` вот так:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[Документация](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging)

Если Spring Boot не используется, то достаточно добавить в зависимости Log4J, и Spring начнёт его использовать. Для Spring 5 нужно добавлять Log4J2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Для Spring 4 - Log4J:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Spring Boot не используется

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: не работает. добавил в зависимости - DEBUG инфа перестала выводится.

Comment: А конфиг log4j у вас есть? А в нём настроен appender для тех пакетов, из которых вы пишете сообщения? А уровень логирования rootLogger случайно не в INFO выставлен? Создайте [минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и добавьте его в вопрос, иначе попытки помочь вам превращаются в гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Добавил в шапку темы конфиг. Если я буду вызывать логер сам то все работает как нужно.

Comment: `com.spring`? У Спринга пакет `org.springframework`. Или `com.spring` - это ваш пакет? Даже если и так, вы же сами уровень info выставляете, неудивительно что debug сообщения пропали.

Comment: Изменил пакет и изменил уровень - не изменилось ничего.